# Centering an equation vertically

Tags: beamer, equations, positioning

I would like to put an equation at the center of a page in beamer (viewing the page from top to bottom rather than left to right - I already know how to center an equation going from left to right). I would also like to have some text above the equation. How can I do both at once?

Comment: So you want the text to appear just below the `\frametitle`, and then the equation is vertically centred on the slide? The simple frame: `\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  Here is some text
  \[
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \]
\end{frame}` produces a centred equation and text *immediately* above it.

Answer (score 1):

`beamer` frames are vertically centered by default unless you have `\documentclass[t]{beamer}` or `\begin{frame}[t]`.
You can use `\vfil` and `\vfill` to accomplish a vertically centered equation and some text that is vertically centered between the top and the equation.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % used to show output debug
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Text over equation
\vfill
\(equatio^n\)
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output without lua-visual-debug] [image: output with lua-visual-debug]

*Is this what you want?*